# Replace fragment in tablayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a parent fragment containing TabLayout and ViewPager.
The TabLayout has 3 tabs (fragments) managed by FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

After the user clicks on a button on the 3 fragment, I would like to replace it with different fragment, without reloading the parent fragment.

I tried to remove the fragment and add the new one and call notifyDataSetChanged() and the fragment is indeed replaced, but the TabLayout custom view headers are gone...

Any idea how can I do it right?

Thanks.

Comment: can you post your code?. it will be easy if have some code posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the 3rd `Fragment` working as a holder for two child `Fragments` which you can switch based on your app's logic (clicking the button you mention).

The key for this alternative is that the 3rd `Fragment` in the `ViewPager` will be the parent of the two `Fragments` that will be switching.

The two child `Fragments` will communicate with the parent `Fragment` for the parent to take care of doing the switching.

For the switching the parent will use a `ChildFragmentManager` instead of the `FragmentManager` used for `Fragments` that are managed by `Activities`.